# How to tell if a vector set is linearly dependent in $\mathbb{C^3}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

> Given set $A=\{(1+i,1,-2i),(1,1-i,2+i),(2+i,2,-3)\}$, is the set linearly dependent in the context of vector space:
>
> 1) $\mathbb{C^3}$ over $\mathbb C$
>
> 2) $\mathbb{C^3}$ over $\mathbb R$

As far as I understand I can present $A$ in the matrix form, then arrive to the row echelon form and check whether a row can become a row of zeroes.

So this is the matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1+i&1&2+i\\
1&1-i&2\\
-2i&2+i&-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

After the following elementary operations:
$$
R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2 \\
R_2 \rightarrow R_2 -(1+i)R_1 \\
R_3 \rightarrow R_3+2iR_1 \\
R_2 \rightarrow -R_2 \\
R_3 \rightarrow -(4+3i)R_2
$$

we arrive to the echelon form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1-i&2\\
0&1&i\\
0&0&2-2i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

1) I think $A$ cannot be linearly dependent when $\mathbb{C^3}$ over $\mathbb C$ because $2-2i\neq 0$ so we can never get a row of zeroes thus we have 3 leading coefficients in $\mathbb{C^3}$ so the set is linearly independent.

2) When $\mathbb{C^3}$ over $\mathbb R$ I don't really know what happens with $i$'s in the reduced matrix.

Comment: If you are viewing $\mathbb{C}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$, you are not allowed to multiply by complex coefficients when you do row operations, only by real coefficients.

Comment: @kccu so what will happen with complex coefficients? Will they become zeroes?

Comment: The complex coefficients in the matrix do no vanish. You are simply limited to using real coefficients in your operations. For instance, on your second operation you use $-(1+i)R_1$, and that is not allowed. You could use $\alpha R_1$ in its stead for any $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri but that way I won't be able to get to the reduced form

Comment: Then try something else! Do you know the classical definition of linear independence via linear combinations?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I'm not sure which one you're referring to but I know this one: given the set of vectors $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{F^n}$ if the equation $x_1a_1+...+x_na_n=0$ results in that $x_1=...=x_n=0$ then the set is linearly independent

Comment: Yes, you can try and use this to determine linear independence. Perhaps more generally, you can use this definition to try and show that if $S\subset\mathbb{C^n}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$, then it also is linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri by that logic, for example if we choose the solution set $(x,y,z)$, I would have $x(1+i)+y\cdot 1 + z(2+i)=0$. Then I'd say that $1+1 \neq 0, 1 \neq 0, 2+i \neq 0$ therefore $x, y, z$ have to be zeroes. And then I'd repeat the same with each row right?

Comment: I will write this down in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the classical definition:

> Let $S=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a subset of a linear space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$. The equation
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i=0$$
>
> in $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in\mathbb{F}$ admits a solution $\alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_n=0$. If  it admits no other solution, then $S$ is said to be **linearly independent**. Otherwise, $S$ is said to be **linearly dependent**.

Our subset has $n=3$ and

$$v_1=(1+i,1,-2i)\\
v_2=(1,1-i,2+i)\\
v_3=(2+i,2,-3)$$

Our linear space is $\mathbb{C}^3$. You have already found an answer for the case $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$; let's tackle the case $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$. Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider a linear combination of the $v_i$

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i=\alpha_1\cdot(1+i,1,-2i)+\alpha_2\cdot(1,1-i,2+i)+\alpha_3\cdot(2+i,2,-3)=\\
\big((\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2\alpha_3)+(\alpha_1+\alpha_3)\cdot i,(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2\alpha_3)-\alpha_2\cdot i, (2\alpha_2-3\alpha_3)+(-2\alpha_1+\alpha_2)\cdot i\big)
\end{align}

Now, if this linear combination is $0$, then we must have that each coordinate is $0$. This also means that for each coordinate, both the real part and the imaginary part must be $0$. Hence, we have a system of equations:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2\alpha_3=0\\
\alpha_1+\alpha_3=0\\
\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2\alpha_3=0\\
\alpha_2=0\\
2\alpha_2-3\alpha_3=0\\
-2\alpha_1+\alpha_2=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

You can solve this however you prefer, but it's easy to see that the only solution to this system is $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=0$. It follows from the definition that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a linearly independent set of $\mathbb{C}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Did you notice that in this solution, we didn't use any particular property that requires the $\alpha_i$ to be real (rather than complex)? Indeed, we have the following:

> **Corollary:** Let $\mathbb{F_1}$ be a field extension of $\mathbb{F_0}$. If $S=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}\subset V$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{F_1}$, then it is linearly independent over $\mathbb{F_0}$.

*Proof:* Observe that any solution $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in\mathbb{F_0}$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i=0$ is also a solution in $\mathbb{F_1}$. Since $S$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{F_1}$, the only solution in $\mathbb{F_1}$ is the trivial, zero solution. It follows that the trivial solution is also the only solution in $\mathbb{F_0}$, and hence $S$ is also linearly independent in $\mathbb{F_0}$, as claimed. $\square$

By the corollary, the fact that you proved linear independence in the case $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ meant you automatically also proved linear independence in the case $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I didn't understand why you broke the vector elements into parts, for example, why instead of writing $(a_1+a_2+2a_3)+(a_1+a_3)\cdot i=0$ you wrote $a_1+a_2+2a_3=0$ and separately $a_1+a_3=0$, specifically why can you assume that sub-parts of the expression are $0$

Comment: The complex number $a+bi$ is $0$ if and only if $a=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: I also didn't understand why we need the corollary. Didn't we assume from the beginning that $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: I think you missed something in the sum of the third coordinate: $-3a_3+(-2a_2+a_2)\cdot 1+\mathbf{2a_2}$

Comment: We don't need the corollary. However, with the corollary, linear independence in $\mathbb{C}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$ follows automatically from linear independence in $\mathbb{C}^3$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Since you had already shown question $(1)$, you could just point to the corollary for the answer to question $(2)$.$${}$$ Also, you are correct with respect to the third coordinate, I will fix it.

Comment: I see the logic of the corollary now. While I understand that trivial solution over $\mathbb C$ will of course be a solution to the system when over $\mathbb R$ but where is the proof in the corollary that it's the only solution when over $\mathbb R$ as well?

Comment: The proof is in the answer, right below the corollary statement. Any solution over $\mathbb{R}$ is also a solution over $\mathbb{C}$, but by hypothesis the only solutions over $\mathbb{C}$ are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Treat $A$ as a matrix whose columns are the given vectors.

Note that $A$ has an eigenvalue of multiplicity one at zero. In particular $\ker A$ is the (complex) span of the corresponding eigenvector.

Hence the columns are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{C}$.

In this case, the eigenvector is (a complex multiple of) $v=(2,-1+i,-1-i)$. Note that there is no $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\lambda v $ is purely real.

Hence the columns are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.